# Seleccionar registros que existen menos de 3 veces en un tabla

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo el siguiente select:

```
select u.idusuario, u.apellido, u.nombre, u.login, u.email 
from USUARIO u left join CREDENCIAL  
c on u.idusuario=c.idusuario
where c.idusuario is NULL
```

Que sirve para traer los registros que no existen en la tabla *Credencial* pero que si existen en la tabla *Usuario*, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para mostrar una vez a todos los usuario que se encuentran que esta repetidos 2, 1 o ninguna vez en la tabla *Credencial*.

Comment: Quiza con un "GROUP BY c.idusuario" puedas hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
select c.idusuario, count(*) as Cantidad
from CREDENCIAL c 
group by c.idusuario
having count(*) >= 3
```

Si necesitas saber quienes son esos usuarios puedes hacer un join con un subquery o con un cte y usar la misma lógica anterior

Comment: Una correción: el usuario que formula la pregunta buscaba recuperar los usuarios repetidos menos de 3 veces en la tabla Credencial, de modo que la condición sería HAVING COUNT(*) < 3

Answer (score 0):

Rescato esta cuestión del baúl porque considero que ninguna de las respuestas aportadas en su día resolvió el problema/requisitos planteados por el autor de la pregunta, si la he interpretado correctamente. Vamos a estudiarlos.

Se tienen dos tablas, `Usuario` y `Credencial` que se relacionan con una cardinalidad de uno a muchos (1:N). Se quiere escribir una consulta que devuelva todos los usuarios con registros en la tabla `Usuario` que tengan menos de tres registros correspondientes en la tabla `Credencial` (< 3). Esto supone mostrar solamente usuarios presentes en `Usuario`, no mostrar usuarios que no estén en esta tabla pero cuyo `IdUsuario` sí sea referenciado en algún registro de `Credencial` y no mostrar tampoco usuarios presentes en ambas tablas pero con 3 o más registros en `Credencial`.

Podemos utilizar las siguientes sentencias DDL-DML para un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Usuario (
  IdUsuario INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Apellido VARCHAR(50),
  Nombre VARCHAR(50),
  Login VARCHAR(50),
  Email VARCHAR(100)
  -- Otras posibles columnas de la tabla Usuario
);

-- Registros de ejemplo de la tabla Usuario
INSERT INTO Usuario (IdUsuario, Apellido, Nombre, Login, Email)
VALUES (1, 'Sorolla', 'Joaquín', 'joaquins', 'joaquins@email.com');

INSERT INTO USUARIO (IdUsuario, Apellido, Nombre, Login, Email)
VALUES (2, 'Dalí', 'Salvador', 'salvadord', 'salvadord@email.com');

INSERT INTO USUARIO (IdUsuario, Apellido, Nombre, Login, Email)
VALUES (3, 'Theotokópoulos', 'Doménikos', 'domenikost', 'domenikost@email.com');

CREATE TABLE CREDENCIAL (
  IdCredencial INT PRIMARY KEY,
  IdUsuario INT,
  -- Otras posibles columnas de la tabla Credencial
);

-- Registros de ejemplo de la tabla Credencial
INSERT INTO Credencial (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (2, 1);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (3, 3);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (4, 3);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (5, 3);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (6, 3);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (7, 4);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (8, 5);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (9, 5);

INSERT INTO CREDENCIAL (IdCredencial, IdUsuario)
VALUES (10, 5);
```

Bajo estas condiciones la *query* aportada por Elena, incluso con la corrección que indico en un comentario, no satisface los requisitos, porque no incorpora el **LEFT JOIN** de rigor y devuelve potencialmente registros de usuarios presentes en `Credencial` que no existen en `Usuario`, tabla que además está siendo ignorada en esta consulta. Comprobémoslo:

```sql
SELECT c.IdUsuario, count(*) AS Cantidad
FROM Credencial c 
GROUP BY c.IdUsuario
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

```swift
+-----------+----------+
| IdUsuario | Cantidad |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        2 |
|         4 |        1 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Como se ve, la consulta de Elena consigue discriminar los usuarios cuyo `IdUsuario` aparece menos de 3 veces, pero solamente en la tabla `Credencial`. Para encontrar los usuarios que aparecen menos de 3 veces en `Credencial` y que, además, cuenten con un registro en la tabla `Usuario` es necesario hacer uso de una combinación mediante [JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver16):

```sql
SELECT u.IdUsuario, COUNT(c.IdUsuario) AS Cantidad
FROM Usuario u
LEFT JOIN Credencial c ON u.IdUsuario = c.IdUsuario
GROUP BY u.IdUsuario
HAVING COUNT(c.IdUsuario) < 3
```

```swift
+-----------+----------+
| IdUsuario | Cantidad |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        2 |
|         2 |        0 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Ahora sí, obtenemos solamente usuarios registrados en la tabla `Usuario`, que tengan un número de ocurrencias o `Cantidad` menor que 3 en la tabla `Credencial`, lo cual:

- Excluye al usuario con `IdUsuario` = 3 porque tiene en total cuatro registros en la tabla `Credencial`.
- Excluye al usuario con `IdUsuario` = 4 porque, aunque tiene menos de tres registros en la tabla `Credencial`, no tiene un registro en la tabla `Usuario`.

Answer (score -1):

Si entendí bien esto es lo que quieres

```
select
    u.idusuario, u.apellido, u.nombre,Count(c.idusuario) as existe
from USUARIO u 
    left join CREDENCIAL c on u.idusuario=c.idusuario
group by c.idusuario
```